# How to sum hours in format 00:00 string in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have one component in react that give me the hours in format "00:00", i need to sum the total of this hours.

I make a action to after search the workouts, sum and give me the sumHoras:

```
export const searchWorkout = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        axios.get(`${URL}`)
            .then((resp) => {
                if(resp.data){
                    dispatch({type: 'WORKOUT_SEARCHED', payload: resp.data})
                    let sumHoras = 0;
                    for(let i=0;i<resp.data.length;i++){
                        sumHoras += resp.data[i].tempoGasto
                    }
                    dispatch({type: 'TEMPOGASTO_CHANGED', payload: sumHoras})
                }
            })
        }
}
```

This reducer `"TEMPOGASTO_CHANGED"` return the total of hours of the resp.data.tempoGasto list.

How i can sum this total of hours?

```
for(let i=0;i<resp.data.length;i++){
     sumHoras += resp.data[i].tempoGasto
}
```

My second tentative:

```
 for(let i=0;i<resp.data.length;i++){
                        var dt = new Date(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                        dt.setHours(dt.getHours() + Number(resp.data[i].tempoGasto.substring(0,2)));      // For the 01:00
                        dt.setMinutes(dt.getMinutes() + Number(resp.data[i].tempoGasto.substring(3,5))); // For the first 00:30
                    }
```

but the hours is not summing and the minutes are returning nan

return me the string: 001:0001:0009:3505:05

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a function that accepts an hours string of the format `HH:MM` and converts it to a decimal hour time, then just sum as you would normally. Currently your approach just does string concatenation, which is why you end up with that strange looking result.

**Example:**

Function:

```js
function hoursStringToDecimal(hoursString) {
    const [hoursPart, minutesPart] = hoursString.split(":");
    return Number(hoursPart) + Number(minutesPart) / 60;
}
```

To sum:

```js
let sumHoras = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < resp.data.length; i++){
     sumHoras += hoursStringToDecimal(resp.data[i].tempoGasto);
}
```

or

```js
const sumHoras = resp.data.reduce((acc, e) => (
    acc + hoursStringToDecimal(e.tempoGasto)
), 0);
```

**Sample:**

Input:

```js
const resp = {
    data: [
        {
            tempoGasto: "01:00",
        },
        {
            tempoGasto: "01:00",
        },
        {
            tempoGasto: "09:35",
        },
        {
            tempoGasto: "05:05",
        },
    ]
}
```

Result for `sumHoras`:

```js
16.666666666666668
```

To convert back to `HH:MM` format, you can use the following function:

```js
function decimalHoursToString(hoursDecimal) {
    const numHours = Math.floor(hoursDecimal);
    const numMinutes = Math.round((hoursDecimal - numHours) * 60);
    return `${numHours < 10 ? "0" : ""}${numHours}:${numMinutes < 10 ? "0" : ""}${numMinutes}`;
}
```

result: `"16:40"`

Comment: Seems that is not a exatcly sum. This doesn't need to result 16:40?

Comment: @yobaxeb Yeah 16:40 as a decimal number of hours is 16.666. Did you want the result format to be in `HH:MM` as well?

Answer (score 0):

One thing I might recommend is getting total *minutes* rather than total hours, so you don't suffer from round-off errors from dealing with 1/60ths of an hour -- or at least delay any such rounding errors to one final step.

The next thing you need to do is treat the string info like two separate numbers.

One way to do that is the `split()` function. If you do this:

`'05:14'.split(':')`

...for example, the result is an array like this:

`['05', '14']`

And while JavaScript will *in some contexts* treat strings as numbers, it's best to be explicit about converting strings to numbers.

So I'd do something like this:

```
let sumMinutos = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < resp.data.length; i++) {
    const [horas, minutos] = resp.data[i].tempoGasto.split(':').map(s => parseInt(s));
    sumMinutos += horas * 60 + minutos;
}

const sumHoras = sumMinutos / 60;
```

Comment: Using only minutes is much cleaner!

Answer (score 0):

I think, the hours in the form hh:mm is just a string. You could parse this into an Date object. But I think it would be simpler to just split the values, parse them into integers and add hours and minutes seperatly up.

```js
const resp = {
  data: [
    {tempoGasto: '01:00'},
    {tempoGasto: '01:00'},
    {tempoGasto: '09:35'},
    {tempoGasto: '05:05'}
  ]
};


const sumHoras = [0, 0];

for (let i=0; i < resp.data.length; i++){
  const [hours, minutes] = resp.data[i].tempoGasto.split(':').map(s => parseInt(s, 10));
  
  // hours
  sumHoras[0] += hours;
  
  // minutes
  if ((sumHoras[i] + minutes) > 59) {
    const diff = sumHoras[1] + minutes - 60;
    sumHoras[0] += 1;
    sumMinutes[1] = diff;
  } else {
    sumHoras[1] += minutes;
  }
}


console.log(sumHoras.join(':'));
```